# How to decompose a relation into BCNF?

Tags: dependencies, key, relation, functional-dependencies, bcnf

Suppose we have a [relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX5l0.png) where:

Patient determines Doctor, Hospital determines Doctor, and Doctor determines Hospital. How would we decompose this into BCNF?

{**Doctor**, **Patient**}, {**Patient**, **Hospital**} or

{**Doctor**, Hospital}, {**Patient**, **Hospital**} or

{**Doctor**, Hospital}, {**Doctor, Patient**}

In my understanding in the relation, it needs to be 3NF and if X → Y holds in R, the one of the following must hold for each dependency in the relation:X → Y is trivially functionally dependent  X is a superkey of R.

So {**Doctor**, Hospital}, {**Doctor, Patient**} would be the correct choice?

Comment: A relation doesn't "need to be in 3nf" plus the rest to be in BCNF; just the rest guarantees BCNF (& 3NF). Although you have garbled the rest. So please look up a definition of BCNF and edit your question..

Answer (score 1):

First, I think that you have misinterpreted the figure. The notation used in it is normally interpreted as describing the following two functional dependencies:

```
Patient, Hospital → Doctor   (1)
Doctor → Hospital            (2)
```

The functional dependency (1) means that to each patient in a certain hospital is assigned a unique doctor, while (2) means that each doctor works in a unique hospital. In your interpretation, instead, each hospital determines uniquely a doctor, that is any hospital has only one doctor!

So, given the above interpretation, let's see if the relation is or not in BCNF. A relation is in BCNF if each determinant is a (super)key, and clearly the dependency:

```
Doctor → Hospital
```

violates this condition, since Doctor is not a superkey (that is it does not determinate all the attributes). In fact this relation has two candidate keys: (Patient, Hospital) and (Patient, Doctor).

So, a decomposition of this relation in BCNF is the following:

```
R1 <(Doctor, Hospital), { Doctor → Hospital }>

R2 <(Doctor, Patient), { }>
```

(so you are correct in your guess).

Note, however, that this decomposition has an unpleasant property: the loss of a functional dependency! In fact, the dependency:

```
Patient, Hospital → Doctor
```

is lost, that is it not enforceable in the resulting database. This means that one could insert information about a patient with a doctor which is not in the hospital in which is the patient!

Finally note that, since Doctor is a prime attribute (that is it belongs to a candidate key), the initial relation is already in 3NF.